# Change the color of Send button of Gmail Compose dialog using chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension in which I want to change the color of the "Send" button of Compose dialog.

What is the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

**Update-**

Here is the function of content.js I am currently using to change the color-

```
function modifySendButton(check, form) {
    var send_button = $(form).siblings('table').find('div[role="button"][aria-label="Send ‪(Ctrl-Enter)‬"]');
    if (0 === send_button.length) {
        send_button = $(this).siblings('table').find('div[role="button"][aria-label="Send ‪(⌘Enter)‬"]');
    }

    if (true === check) {
        send_button.addClass("active-send-button");
    } else {
        send_button.removeClass("active-send-button");
    }
}
```

It is changing the Send button color, but I want to know is it the right way to do so?

Comment: Did you try to create extension with a content-script?

Comment: Yes, I have a content script.

Comment: So, can you share your code with us? And where exactly did you stuck in?

Comment: Hello @Deliaz, I have added the code snippet. Please review it and tell me is it the right way to change the color of Send button?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) inside the content-script.

Complete example:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Btn Color",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["content-script.js"],
    "matches": [
      "https://mail.google.com/*"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

**content-script.js**

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if(mutation.addedNodes && mutation.addedNodes.length) {

            // look for the button
            const sendBtn = document.querySelector('.dw [aria-label*="Send"]'); 
            if(sendBtn) {
                sendBtn.style.background = 'red'; // set your styles
            }

        }
    });    
});

var targetNode = document.body;
observer.observe(targetNode, {childList: true});
```